# How to insert image into SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert image into `SQLite` data base but i am getting `null` point exception, But checked there is no any `null object`. I tried my level best but still i cannot find the  problem help me. My tried code is shown below. Thank you stack overflow and help me please,

## MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
Button button;
Bitmap bitmap;
Context context;

LocalDatabase localDatabase;
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageid);
    localDatabase=new LocalDatabase(this);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try {
            iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
            saveimage(inputData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
boolean saveimage(byte[] bytes)
{
    localDatabase.insertImage(bytes);
    return true;
}
}
```

## LocalDataBase.class

```
public class LocalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String IMAGE_ID = "id";
public static final String IMAGE = "image";
LocalDatabase localDatabase;


private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Images.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String IMAGES_TABLE = "ImagesTable";

private static final String CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + IMAGES_TABLE + " (" +
                IMAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + IMAGE + " BLOB NOT NULL );";

public LocalDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    mDb.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

// Insert the image to the Sqlite DB
public void insertImage(byte[] imageBytes) {
     mDb=localDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(IMAGE, imageBytes);
    mDb.insert(IMAGES_TABLE, null, cv);
    localDatabase.close();
}

// Get the image from SQLite DB
// We will just get the last image we just saved for convenience...
public byte[] retreiveImageFromDB() {
    Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, IMAGES_TABLE, new String[]{IMAGE,},
            null, null, null, null,
            IMAGE_ID + " DESC", "1");
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(IMAGE));
        cur.close();
        return blob;
    }
    cur.close();
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: inserting images to SQLite database is bad practise

Comment: now just i am trying to insert image into the table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041107/android-sqlite-database-blob-datatype

Comment: then which one is good practice #godwin

Comment: Please consider reducing your code into a [mcve].

Comment: A good practice is to simply store the image **paths** (or URLs). Not the physical data.

Comment: Aside from all the comments explaining you that it is not a good idea to do that, you should provide a stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: If i store image path , after inserting image path if i delete original image  in my mobile i will get any problem ..? @modularSynth

Comment: Self understandably, yes - of course. But what's the point to delete the image from the path? In both cases, the storage space occupied by the image data would be the same. And anyway, you are supposed to handle the error - and possibly also have a "No pitcture available" alternative (As a text and/or an image).

Comment: thank you for valuable  info. but can i insert byte array to the Sqlite data base or not @ mondularSynth

Comment: You **can**. But you **should not**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

then insert the bytearray to database having the column type as blob